# Why does quitting ipdb while inside a cmd.Cmd subclass function exit the function?

Tags: python, cmd, ipdb

I have a little cmd subclass:

```
class Foo(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_ipdb(self, *a, **kw):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        pass

Foo().cmdloop()
```

This works and lets me inside ipdb, but when exiting, either using 'q' or CTRL-D, the cmdloop also breaks (which is not desired)

I tried wrapping the ipdb with a try / except, but I don't get to the except part. How can I maintain the cmdloop after exiting form ipdb?

*BTW, I saw that cmd2 already does what I'm trying to do (with its default `python` option), but I still wonder what is happening here in the old cmd*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ipdb [documentation](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb), ipdb exposes

> same interface as the pdb module

The [pdb docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) for [q](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-quit)(uit) state:

> Quit from the debugger. The program being executed is aborted.

So when you press 'q', both the debugger *and* the running program exit.

You may want to use a different pdb command, such as [c](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-continue)(ontinue):

> Continue execution, only stop when a breakpoint is encountered.